# Creating a running clock using moment & moment-timezone in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, momentjs

I'm trying to create a react component that renders a ticking clock. I'm using moment and moment-timezone for different time-zones. I was able to create a component with a static clock (doesn't increment), but I'm unable to create a ticking clock. Code is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';

export default class TimeClock extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { time: moment().clone().tz(this.props.timezone).toLocaleString() };
      this.displayTime = this.displayTime.bind(this);
    }

    displayTime(){
        //let now = moment();
        //let location = now.clone().tz(this.props.timezone);
        this.setState({
            time: moment().clone().tz(this.props.timezone).toLocaleString()
        });
        //return location.toLocaleString();
    }
    render(){
        //let now = moment();
        //let location = now.clone().tz(this.props.timezone);
        //let timezone = this.props.timezone;
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.props.timezone}</p>
                <p>{setInterval(this.displayTime,1000)}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Note: its being passed a prop (timezone) from App.js, a parent component.

Current code outputs the following:

```
Australia/Melbourne

#######
```

where ####### represents some number that started at 5 or 6 and is increasing rapidly.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: soon after posting this question, I found the following link ([Where to apply my moment() function in a react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34621442/where-to-apply-my-moment-function-in-a-react-component)), which I adapted to my code and got it working, but I don't understand why my attempt didn't work. I'm new to react.

Comment: WRT moment, use `format`, not `toLocaleString`, and also you don't need to clone or get now in local time.  `moment.tz(thetimezone).format(yourdesiredformat)` will work.

Comment: yeah I should have removed that code with the "now" and "location" variable since I wasn't using those. I'll edit the code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code does not render anything related to the current time. This line:

```
<p>{setInterval(this.displayTime,1000)}</p>
```

does not print the current time - it displays created interval's ID, because that's what is returned by `setInterval()` function.

So, first of all, you should change this line to display the time, based on Component's state. This can be done like this:

```
<p>{this.state.time}</p>
```

Another thing you have to do is to properly create the interval. Setting it in `render()` method is not a good idea, because you will create a new interval

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Arrow function allows you to use "this" in context of the Component
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.displayTime();
    }), 1000);
}
```

(you should also remember to deactivate the interval once component is removed from the view).

Comment: is there a reason why the function is called componentDidMount() or is that just by convention?

Comment: It's called like that because it is invoked when "the component did mount", simple as that. You can read more about this at React's documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html